# Not able to detect faces using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to detect faces in an image using OpenCV in android.

here is the `scanFaces` function which is using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml) classifier.

Since I am new, I am not sure if I am loading the classifier in the right way.

```
 private void scanFaces(Uri imageUri) throws Exception {
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeBitmapUri(this, imageUri);
        Mat Rgba = new Mat();
        Mat grayMat= new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, Rgba);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(Rgba, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
        File mCascadeFile = new File("file:///assets/classifier.xml");

    

    try{
        cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("cascadeClassifier: ",""+e);
    }

    grayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    if (cascadeClassifier != null) {
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayMat, faces, 1.1, 2, 2,
                new Size(absoluteFaceSize, absoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }
    Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <facesArray.length; i++)
           Core.rectangle(grayMat, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 3);

    try{
        Utils.matToBitmap(grayMat,grayBitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("","");
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(grayBitmap);

}
```

The tutorial which I was following accessed the classifier in this way:

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
            File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);


            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();

            // Load the cascade classifier
            cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

If you want to take a look at the tutorial here is the [link](https://www.mirkosertic.de/blog/2013/07/realtime-face-detection-on-android-using-opencv/)

-Thanks

Comment: whats the problem you are facing? Does it throw any error?

Comment: no errors, it doesn't detect any faces

Comment: @sidd Then [edit] the question to faithfully represent that. If you can't detect faces in the first place, drawing some rectangles is irrelevant.